# Android - What´s the point of Google Repository package

Tags: android

What´s the point of `Google Repository` package that just updated to revision 18?

What need that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Google Repository** is a Maven repository and the Gradle plugin automatically add it to your list of repositories.

It is necessary if you want to use Google Play Services in Android Studio:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

Comment: the library just went from v17 to v18, does it affect play-services versions? where can I see google libraries versions?

Comment: No, it doesn't affect the Play Services version. Maybe the update is only a bug fix or an improvement of Maven repository. The last version of Google Play Services is 7.3 of April 2015, as you can see here https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

All your support packages, Google play services libraries will be loaded locally from the Google Repository and it is necessary to update it to the latest version to have the latest play services in your library

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the other answers, the main reason for it is that Google's lawyers require you to accept the click-through terms of service before letting you use those libraries.  Otherwise, they'd probably put them up on Maven Central or wherever the cool kids keep their libraries these days.

With the local Google Repository, you can still include and access their libraries as if they were on one of those usual sites, but it keeps the legal squad happy.